# Managing Facebook Timeline with API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I've seen plenty of documentation for how to add items to a user's timeline, but nothing on how to edit/remove existing items.

As far as I can tell there is nothing in place to edit/hide/feature an activity other than doing it manually by the user. I suspect that timeline management isn't allowed, much like the ability to manage friends, but figured I'd ask in case anybody had tried with any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, there's no API that allows removal of content from a profile/timeline (except for posts made by an app, which can be removed by the same app)